# How to fix no [query] registered for [field] in elasticsearch repository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I want to find list of products by a collection of vendor ids. The query should be like this: select * from product where vendorid in({list of vendor ids}).

below is the elasticsearch query that I use:

```
@Query("{\"bool\" : {\"must\" : {\"bool\" : {\"should\" : [ {\"field\" : {\"vendor\" : \"?\"}}, {\"field\" : {\"vendor\" : \"?\"}} ]}}}}")
    List<WarehouseProductDTO> findByVendorIds(List<Long> vendorIds);
```

When I run the project, it says no [query] registered for [field]

Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `field` by `terms` like this:

```
@Query("{\"bool\" : {\"must\" : {\"bool\" : {\"should\" : [ {\"terms\" : {\"vendor\" : ?0}} ]}}}}")
List findByVendorIds(List vendorIds);
```